# Mobile site - doesn't scroll at all

Tags: css, mobile, scroll, viewport

I've googled everywhere - my site has no fixed heights, no fixed placements. It shows the viewport as I'd like, but ONLY that. It doesn't scroll or show anything else.

What am I missing? I've tried all sort of overflow options, nothing seems to be working.

Comment: What are you using to make this mobile site? Are you trying to do it with something like JQuery Mobile, or something along those lines?

Comment: It's my first stab at screen to mobile - test site @ http://ec2-50-17-62-163.compute-1.amazonaws.com/static/index.html - enjoy typing that into a phone!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would do the following...

1. I would first temporarily disable/remove the stylesheets to make sure everything is spiffy as plain html (if you still have an issue without the stylsheets, there is probably a js script wrecking chaos)
2. I would search for position absolute(specifically on a wrapper,content, or sidebar element) in the stylesheet.  This is often the #1 killer for scrollability on iOS/mobile phone devices.

Comment: Thanks! adding and removing to find the culprit!

Answer (score 7):

BODY and HTML tags are 100% in height and so is your .wrapper

```
html, body {min-height:100%; height:100%; overflow-x:hidden; display:block;}
```

Try removing the height from .wrapper

```
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

If you experience content overflowing, add `overflow: hidden` to .wrapper

Comment: removed wrapper's 100% height in the screen and antiscreen css - no change.

Comment: I just tried on my iPhone. Remove the min-height:100%; height:100%; also from html and body, try that?

Comment: Different site, similar problem.

Found that removing `height: 100%` on `html, body` fixes smooth scrolling on iPhone 3, also fixed scrolling on an Android device (Samsung). Did not have 100% height on wrapper.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was loading a YouTube video on my site using an iframe loaded by JavaScript slider.  This caused a problem with Android which did not allow scrolling and zooming of the page.  It had nothing to do with setting CSS "html, body" heights or overflow hiddens.  Once I got rid of my YouTube video inside the jQuery slider plugin, website scrolling and zooming started working just fine on the Android phone.

Answer (score -1):

Trying removing the last javascripts added on your html!I found that my site doesn't scroll on mobiles because a javascript. 
Best regards,